# How do you add the sqlite3 framework for a mobile substrate hack

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, cydia

Im creating a mobile substrate hack and i need to add the sqlite3 framework but i have no idea how to add it to the makefile.  I tried adding "sqlite3" to the MyTweak_FRAMEWORKS but that didnt work.

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = MyTweak
MyTweak_FILES = Tweak.xm
MyTweak_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit AddressBook AddressBookUI AudioToolbox Foundation SystemConfiguration QuartzCore CoreGraphics 

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk
include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/bundle.mk
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to add the following line to your makefile

```
MyTweak_LDFLAGS = -lsqlite3
```

Comment: the format for adding additional ones is -lname, where name is the name of the framework.  Dont forgot to put -l in front!  -L as in lollipop.

Comment: So it actually links... Does it link against an apple-provided libsqlite3 or a saurik-provided one?